# Check whether an uploaded file is a CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I want to test if the uploaded file is a CSV file, after selecting a csv file then confirm with this code and still give me the message that not a CSV file please help me out.

```
if($_FILES["file"]["type"] <> "application/vnd.ms-excel"){
   die("This is not a CSV file.");
}
```

Comment: csv files are not excel files.

Comment: Why don't you just dump the type that comes back, and test against that?

Comment: If it's a text file, it may or may not be a CSV file. You can only really know if you try to parse it. Also, never use `$_FILES['type']` for anything, as that is completely unverified data.

Comment: True. If you want to make sure your csv is legit, regex it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest check is "does the file name end in `.csv`".  This will get you most of the way, but it is possible that someone could try and upload something else with a CSV extension.

Your next check should be that the file is text (rather than binary; note that Excel files should fail this).  To do this, check the [ascii representation of each character](http://www.asciitable.com/): apart from carriage returns, line feeds and tabs, there should be no values less than 32.

Once you know that the file is text, you can run it through a [CSV parser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and see if the result is nonsense or not.

Comment: @Anders: Nicely called; I've fixed the text.